# SQL comparison condition column to choose the table to JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

**GENERAL** table:

```
| id | name | type_id |
```

**SECONDARY1** table:

```
| id | general_id | erynda_kakayato | byaka |
```

**SECONDARY2** table:

```
| id | general_id | konkretnaya_hren |
```

How to combine GENERAL table and one of the SECONDARY using the value of the column to GENERAL.TYPE_ID?
The following query does not work, but the logic should be like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM GENERAL  
   JOIN (CASE WHEN types_id = 1 THEN  'SECONDARY1' 
              WHEN types_id = 2 THEN  'SECONDARY2' END) AS t  
      ON GENERAL.id = t.id
```

This request is necessary because values of type changing table for the join. Use of the same table impossible because the property and the number of columns in different tables depending on the column type GENERAL.

Comment: If you're using Postgres you should look at table inheritance. It's generally a much better way to handle stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the value in the `select`.  If using `left join`, you can choose the first non-`NULL` value:

```
select g.*, coalesce(s1.erynda_kakayato, konkretnaya_hren)
from general g left join
     secondary1 s1 
     on s1.general_id = g.id and g.type_id = 1 left join
     secondary s2
     on s2.general_id = g.id and g.type_id = 2 ;
```

Comment: different number of columns in the SECONDARY tables

Comment: @Kul . . . Just choose the columns that you want.  You should edit the question and provide sample results.

Comment: Your solution is interesting, but not that ... I realized that another way to solve it will not work, or to make the same column, or use the programming language to handle the comparison. Your and Giorgos Betsos solution really helped to understand the problem. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT g.* 
FROM GENERAL AS g
LEFT JOIN SECONDARY1 AS s1 
   ON CASE WHEN g.type_id = 1 THEN g.id END = s1.general_id
LEFT JOIN SECONDARY2 AS s2
   ON CASE WHEN g.type_id = 2 THEN g.id END = s2.general_id
```

If `type_id = 1` then only the first `LEFT JOIN` operation is essentially performed, because the `ON` clause of the second `LEFT JOIN` becomes `NULL = s2.general_id`, which can *never* evaluate to `true`.

Comment: It is better to use `ON g.type_id = 1 AND g.id = s1.general_id`. It gives postgres more ways to optimize the query.

Comment: Your solution was almost right. But if you use LEFT JOIN, and if in GENERAL will be 5 rows, and in SECONDARY(1 or 2) is empty, then the result still returns all 5 rows. Can all SECONDARY to create the same BOOLEAN column with a NOT NULL value and test it, but then the result will have duplicate BOOLEAN column with different values. And the result will include all columns from all tables SECONDRAY that bad.